# Tensorflow SVM estimator issue with undefined tensor shape

Tags: tensorflow, svm, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to train a model using Tensorflow's [SVM canned estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/SVM). My input data is a queue sourced from Big Query using Tensorflow's [BigQueryReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cloud/BigQueryReader) which then feeds a shuffle_batch queue. My features are Rank 2 and my example keys are Rank 1. The actual shape of the key and feature tensors aren't fully defined since the number of training/eval examples can vary. I am getting the following error during training:

```
 File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/tensorflow/contrib/linear_optimizer/python/ops/sdca_ops.py", 
 line 313, in minimize example_state_data =self._hashtable.lookup(example_ids_hashed) 
 File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/linear_optimizer/python/ops/sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.py", 
 line 108, in lookup self._check_keys(keys) 
 File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/linear_optimizer/python/ops/sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.py", 
 line 99, in _check_keys keys.get_shape()) 
 ValueError: Key shape must be fully defined, got (?, 2)
```

The issue seems to be tied specifically to the processing of the example key tensor. Has anyone else run into this issue? I have tried very similar code with the other canned estimators and haven't gotten a complaint about the shape not being fully defined. However, this is the first estimator that required keys. When the data is parsed by parse_example after being read from BigQuery, the output are Rank-2 tensors with shape (?,1). In order to create a rank-1 tensor for the keys I am using the reshape function which results in shape (?,). I'm not sure if this could be contributing to my problem:

```
features = tf.parse_example(examples_serialized, features=FEATURES)
features[key_column] = tf.reshape(features[key_column],[-1])
```

Comment: If you just want to remove '1' dimensions, you can use `tf.squeeze()` instead of `tf.reshape()`. Also if you need to calculate dynamically the shape, you can use `tf.shape()`.

Comment: @ManoloSantos I originally used tf.squeeze() but I ran into an error even earlier in the processing because squeeze produced shape unknown as opposed to (?,)  `File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 766, in _shuffle_batch shapes = _shapes([tensor_list], shapes, enqueue_many) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 632, in _shapes raise ValueError("Cannot infer Tensor's rank: %s" % tl[i]) ValueError: Cannot infer Tensor's rank: Tensor("Squeeze:0", dtype=string)`